# Going crazy with the display font awesome icons in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome-5

I'm developing a Django WebApp and using Bootstrap 4, and I want to add icons to my WebApp. Bootstrap recommends Font Awesome on its page, but I'm going crazy because I've tried a thousand ways and there's no way to get the icons added to my website.

Would someone recommend me?
Any help is very precious.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="/my_path/fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web/css/fontawesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="my_path/fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web/css/brands.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="my_path/fontawesome-free-5.12.1-web/css/solid.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
      <i class="fas fa-camera"></i> 
</body>
```

Comment: why does one href start with "/my_path" and the others start with "my_path"

Comment: When you store font awesome in your local system without fonts then you might not be able to see icons. So I refer please try with script URL.

Comment: As a quick test, just paste the font awesome path in browser directly check if it loading

Answer (score 0):

Please check if font awesome is loaded properly.
Or Try with font awesome version 4.
Add script tag.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

```
<i class="fa fa-car"></i>
```